exporting multiple files from a project in a typescript monorepo
I have a mono repo with two typescript projects. ProjectB references functions from ProjectA.
project A package.json
{
  "name": "@monorepo/utils",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "The package containing some utility functions",
  "main": "./build/index.js",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --build"
  }
}

src/index.ts
 export function isEven(n: number): boolean {
  return n % 2 === 0
}

src/maths.ts
export function Add(a: number, b: number): number {
    return a + b
}

project B package.json
{
  "name": "@monorepo/ui",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "The UI package",
  "main": "./build/index.js",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@monorepo/utils": "^1.0.0",
  }
}

The issue I'm having is in project B
projectb/src/app.ts
import { isEven } from "@monorepo/utils"
import { Add } from "@monorepo/utils/build/maths"

It seems fine to me to be importing IsEven from @monorepo/utils, however seems 'wrong' to me to have to specify @monorepo/utils/build/maths. Specifically the 'build' part of that path. Perhaps I'm just being picky, but this seems out of place. I want to refer to the source code, not a build structure.
Is there a better way to do this? Googling around I'm finding people writing scripts to generate imports and exports in an index.ts file... but that seems pretty out there too. Is there some clean way to deal with this?
I hope that makes sense. Thank you! :-)

I ended up writing a tool to generate index.ts.
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

// Get the current directory name
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

function generateExports(targetDir) {
    const srcDir = path.join(targetDir, 'src');
    console.log(`Generating exports for directory: ${srcDir}`);
    if (!fs.existsSync(srcDir)) {
        console.error(`The directory ${srcDir} does not exist.`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    const indexFile = path.join(srcDir, 'index.ts');

    // Function to recursively find all TypeScript files except .test.ts files
    function findAllFiles(dir, fileList = []) {
        const files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
        files.forEach((file) => {
            const filePath = path.join(dir, file);
            if (fs.statSync(filePath).isDirectory()) {
                findAllFiles(filePath, fileList);
            }
            else if (file.endsWith('.ts') && file !== 'index.ts' && !file.endsWith('.test.ts')) {
                fileList.push(filePath);
            }
        });
        return fileList;
    }

    // Get all TypeScript files except index.ts and .test.ts files
    const files = findAllFiles(srcDir);
    if (files.length === 0) {
        console.warn(`No TypeScript files found in ${srcDir}`);
    } else {
        console.log(`Found TypeScript files: ${files.map(s => `${s}\r\n`)}`);
    }

    // Generate export statements
    const exportStatements = files
        .map((file) => {
            const relativePath = path.relative(srcDir, file).replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/\.ts$/, '');
            return `export * from './${relativePath}';`;
        })
        .join('\n');

    // Generate namespace export statements
    const namespaceImportStatements = files
        .map((file) => {
            const relativePath = path.relative(srcDir, file).replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/\.ts$/, '');
            const moduleName = relativePath.replace(/[\/\\\.-]/g, '_');
            return `import * as ${moduleName} from './${relativePath}';`;
        })
        .join('\n');

    const namespaceExportStatements = files
        .map((file) => {
            const relativePath = path.relative(srcDir, file).replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/\.ts$/, '');
            const moduleName = relativePath.replace(/[\/\\\.-]/g, '_');
            return `export { ${moduleName} };`;
        })
        .join('\n');

    const namespaceContent = `${namespaceImportStatements}\n\n${namespaceExportStatements}`;

    // Write to index.ts
    const content = `${exportStatements}\n\n${namespaceContent}`;
    fs.writeFileSync(indexFile, content);
    console.log(`Generated exports in ${indexFile}`);
}

// Get the target directory from command-line arguments
const targetDir = process.argv[2];
if (!targetDir) {
    console.error('Please provide a target directory.');
    process.exit(1);
}
generateExports(targetDir);

Executed in package.json as such.
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "node ../tools/utils/exportFunctions.mjs ../types",
    "build": "tsc --build --verbose"
  },

